# Plivo Browser SDK - How can I transfer a call?

Tags: javascript, php, voip, plivo

I'm stuck with Plivo with how to interact with calls, I have the Browser SDK example setup and can login with an endpoint account and make calls, however I want to extend this and include an option to transfer a call to an audio recording.

Looking at the API, it looks like I need to use the "Transfer a call" feature, and provide the  XML for the leg URL.

What I can't understand is how I call these features in Browser SDK/Javascript and how I identify the call?

Thanks in advance

Matt

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://api-reference.plivo.com/latest/php/resources/call/record-calls/start-recording-a-call) for recording calls are thorough and should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't actually want to record calls, I just want to play an audio message. However, what I don't really understand is how to interact with a call initiated from the Browser SDK